# Bin packing problem : Bins are selected non-sequentially

Tags: linear-programming, or-tools, mixed-integer-programming

I am working on a simple bin-packing problem, what I realize is that the solver is choosing the optimal number of bins to pack items, however, the bins are not contiguous.

Below is my program:

```py
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

s = pywraplp.Solver("", pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)

num_bins = 10
num_items = 10
c = 10
w = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2]


x = {}
for i in range(num_items):
    for j in range(num_bins):
        x[i, j] = s.BoolVar("")

y = {}
for i in range(num_bins):
    y[i] = s.BoolVar("")

# minimize the number of bins used
obj = sum(y[j] for j in range(num_bins))

# pack each item in exactly one bin
for i in range(num_items):
    s.Add(sum(x[i, j] for j in range(num_bins)) == 1)

# bin capacity constraint
for j in range(num_bins):
    s.Add(sum(w[i] * x[i, j] for i in range(num_items)) <= c * y[j])

# solve
s.Minimize(obj)
s.Solve()

bin_for_item = [-1 for i in range(num_items)]

for i in range(num_items):
    for j in range(num_bins):
        if x[i, j].SolutionValue() > 0.5:
            bin_for_item[i] = j

print(f"number of bins = {s.Objective().Value()}")
print(f"Bin assignment for each item: {bin_for_item}")
```

Solver packs the items into bins indexed by `[7, 7, 2, 7, 5, 2, 5, 7, 2, 2]`

It would have been prudent to pick bins numbered from `0, 1, 2`

Comment: please do not use CBC. It is really bad. Use SCIP or CP-SAT.

Answer (score 2):

You can (and should) enforce an order for bins to be used such that bin `i+1` is only allowed to be used if bin `i` is already used. This is because all the bins are indistinguishable.

These are called symmetry breaking constraints, generally they are redundant, yet they can help solvers under some conditions.

additional constraint:

```
for i in range(num_bins - 1):
    s.Add(y[i + 1] <= y[i])
```

Now, the selection of bins is as follows:
`[0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1]`.
So, only first 3 bins are used which is the behaviour we wanted